# Send the SIGHUP signal to a process in Perl

Tags: perl, signals, setuid

I have a UNIX daemon, which wait of SIGHUP for refresh a data. I try to send a signal from the Perl script (under Apache www-data:www-data on the same server) by Proc::Killall ("killall('HUP', 'mydaemon');"), but I have no properly permissions. suid bit doesn't work too. 'kill -n HUP ' from shell are working.

Does you have any idea to do this?

Comment: OK, i will search another method, without a signals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual work-around is to employ a »touch file« to indicate a reload, see [Apache2::Reload](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Reload.html#Special__Touch__File) for a real life example.

Listen to notifications set up with e.g. [File::ChangeNotify](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aChangeNotify) or [AnyEvent::Inotify::Simple](http://p3rl.org/AnyEvent%3a%3aInotify%3a%3aSimple), then do your reloading.