# Run Script on Signal

Tags: perl

I'm trying to build an event queue.  I want to be able to add records to the event queue table in my DB, then have a separate script go through and execute the events.

Is there a way to have that "Executer" script sit there waiting until it gets the signal that an event has been added to the table?  Obviously, I can't randomly query the DB, because that would be very wasteful.

I know this is a broad question, so not asking for a hand-holding, just a point in the right direction.

Comment: I believe semaphores must be the answer, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Try this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489343/send-the-sighup-signal-to-a-process-in-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you database has anything to address this, its going to be database specific. For example, in PostgreSQL you could use `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY`.

You could also use other things to notify the executor to wake up, from a simple system signal (of the `$SIG{...}` variety), to a UDP packet, to a full-on job queuing & notification system.

But really, I doubt you need to worry about this. Have you actually timed how long a trivial select to check for work takes? Probably in the single-millisecond range. If you poll the database every few seconds, the performance impact will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Some DBMS supports that. As example in MySQL you can use UDF and execute external program from trigger. What DBMS are you using?